# How do I allocate memory with cudaHostAlloc() for a c++ vector?

Tags: c++11, cuda

I need to be able to initialize a vector in the GPU without incurring the crazy memory copy overhead. (My GPU shares physical memory with my GPU).

Comment: Its not a duplicate. cudaMallocManaged does a memory copy under the hood. I don't want a memory copy.

Comment: It is a duplicate. Your question is "can I allocate memory  for std::vector using a CUDA host API". The answer is the same -- no unless you write your own model of std;;allocator which calls that CUDA API internally to allocate memeory.